# Why can the main thread of a browser still respond to user input normally after being blocked?

Tags: javascript

1. click `lock 5s` button: JavaScript enters a dead loop. Browser main thread blocked
2. Within five seconds of being locked, enter any amount of text in the input or click the btn button any number of times.
3. Waiting for unlocking. Then you will find that the console suddenly prints a lot of text.

My expectation is that user actions will not be responded to during the blocking process. When the lock is released, the console only outputs `start lock` and `end lock`. But in fact, it's not like that, so I'm very confused.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button id="lock">lock 5s</button>
  <button id="btn">btn</button>
  <script>
    document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("input", () => {
      console.log("on input", input.value);
    });

    document.querySelector("#lock").addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("start lock");
      const start = performance.now();
      while (performance.now() - start < 5000) continue;
      console.log("end lock");
    });
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("btn");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your just queuing events up, after 5 seconds those events get processed.  What effect are you expecting?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's not getting killed, it's just the event loop has been blocked.  Browsers will kill a process, but you will get something like. Oh Snap, and it's longer than 5 seconds before that will kick in.

Comment: @Keith you're right - I misread the code thinking it was in a long loop not locking for 5 seconds * n

Comment: @Keith My expectation is that user actions will not be responded to during the blocking process. When the lock is released, the console only outputs start lock and end lock. But in fact, it's not like that, so I'm very confused.

Comment: "*My expectation is that user actions will not be responded to during the blocking process*" they aren't - the thread is blocked, therefore no event is being processed. But the events are still happening. If that wasn't how browsing works, can you imagine how immensely frustrating using them would be? You'd be typing and the thread blocks for 0.1ms at the exact time you produce a keystroke, which means you've missed a letter. And *thousands* of variations of these all would be happening literally constantly any time you try to interact with a website.

Comment: @VLAZ Your analysis is very reasonable.

Comment: @VLAZ i suspect the events could be queued even on the OS' level. so when the process is awake it starts pulling the queued events in the main process event loop

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Keyboard events and similar would come from the OS but then the browser handles what happens with those. It's the UI thread which is busy, thus the UI is not updating. The browser itself is not "frozen" by the UI thread and can handle things in the background.

Comment: @VLAZ could you check my code snippet? I can't figure why the first click still targets the button

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev you mean the first code block? If so, because the event would bubble up to the body, so clicking the lock button would still be caught at the top level. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @VLAZ after clicking the lock, i click the btn several times. after the locking is over, the first click is registered to the body (I didn't expect that), the rest of clicks is regestered to HTML (I expected that). So my question why the first click was on the btn...

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev You mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMJHX.gif), right? Clicking on "btn" before the UI updates. Well, it's *moved* but the UI hasn't updated to show its new position. [Compare with clicking where it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebDbH.gif) (edited last link since I used the wrong GIF)

Comment: @VLAZ yes, i meant that (your first GIF). Booom!, i've mistaken the lock button's click against the btn click. So everything is OK, I've fixed my expectations, the behavior is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the events are queued.

An interesting case that shows that events are processed after the macrotask is complete.

When the lock is over we add a DIV that pushes the button down.

Then the queued events are processed against the updated DOM (without re-rendering).
Since there's no button anymore under the points the mouse was clicked the mouse events goes into the body.

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
  <button id="lock">lock 5s</button>
  <button id="btn">btn</button>
  <script>
    document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("input", () => {
      console.log("on input", input.value);
    });

    document.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.id !== 'lock' && console.log('body clicked', e.target));

    document.querySelector("#lock").addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("start lock");
      const start = performance.now();
      while (performance.now() - start < 5000) continue;    
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class="test">TEST</div>');  
      console.log("end lock");
    });
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("btn");
    });
  </script>
```

The seconds example make it more obvious that the events goes against the updated DOM, before any rendering:

1. Click the lock btn
2. Click in the space where the 'btn' was before jumping lower

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
  <button id="lock">lock 5s</button>
  <button id="btn">btn</button>
  <script>
    document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("input", () => {
      console.log("on input", input.value);
    });
    
    document.querySelector("#lock").addEventListener("click", async () => {
      console.log("start lock");
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class="test">TEST</div>');  
      await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r));
      const start = performance.now();
      while (performance.now() - start < 5000) continue;    
      document.querySelector('.test').remove()
      console.log("end lock");
    });
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("btn");
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Your example is very interesting.The computer remembered the user's previous actions, waited for the loop to end, and then replayed it again.

Comment: @user15163984 yes, replayed against the updated DOM... but not yet rendered!

Answer (score 0):

Blocking the main JS thread is something you want to avoid..

If your just wanting to disable user interaction for 5 seconds, one idea is just place a div full screen over your page, you could have it set to transparent.

Alternatively you could even create a `<dialog/>` element informing the user, rather than locking up the UI.  Doing this click events are still processed in the event loop, and then won't stack as in your example.

eg.

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
const btnLock = document.querySelector('#lock');

btnLock.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const eatClicks = e => e.stopPropagation();
  dialog.addEventListener('click', eatClicks);
  dialog.showModal();
  setTimeout(() => {
    dialog.close();
    dialog.removeEventListener('click', eatClicks);
  }, 5000);
});

document.addEventListener('click', e =>    console.log('body clicked', e.target));
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button id="lock">lock 5s</button>
<button id="btn">btn</button>

<dialog>Please wait..</dialog>
```